# Identify last element of array - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a file path for example: **new/lib/java.exe**
I would like to get rid of the root folder new and restructure the new path as **lib/java.exe**

**Problem**: I am ending up getting the path as lib/java.exe/ instead. I don't want to have "/" in the end. 
Please have a look at the code that I tried. Please help me resolve this problem.

```
function myFunction() {
    var path=''; 
    var str = "new/lib/java.exe";
    var res = str.split("/");
    if(res.length>0)     //getting rid of the 1st element "new"
       res.shift();

   for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){
      if(res.length ==1){
        path = res[i];
      }
      else{
        path += res[i] + "/"; //***May be this is the problem***
      }
    }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = path;
}
```

Comment: The opposite of `.split()` is `.join()`...

Comment: OMG ! How could I miss thinking about join !! That was so simple. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `shift` either: `res = str.split('/').slice(1).join('/')`

Answer (score 0):

An [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will do.

```
function myFunction() {
    var path = '';
    var str = "new/lib/java.exe";
    var res = str.split("/");
    if (res.length > 0)     //getting rid of the 1st element "new"
        res.shift();
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.join('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array, and shift the value.

```
var str = "new/lib/java.exe";
var arr = str.split('/');

arr.shift();
var joined = arr.join('/');
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure why I did not think about join and made a simple thing unnecessarily complex.